# Where the following objects are stored in memory?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TEXT "Good luck on this test"
int main () {
  char* cPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(TEXT));
  strncpy(cPtr,TEXT,sizeof(TEXT));
  printf("%s\n",cPtr);
  free(cPtr);
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

1. The memory for variable `cPtr`?
2. The address to which `cPtr` points?
3. The code for `malloc()`?
4. The code that `malloc()` calls to move the *brk pointer* for the
   process running this program?

I think its:

1. Heap
2. Stack
3. Data segment
4. Shared library memory

**Is it correct?**

Comment: I don't believe 3. is correct. The `TEXT` macro would be stored in the data segment though.

Comment: Some systems don't have a heap or a stack

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888810/1541563)?

Comment: An answer to this question would be platform specific.

Comment: I think 1 and 2 are backwards. `char *cPtr` is on the stack. "The address to which `cPtr` points" sounds like they're asking about the memory allocated by `malloc`; that's on the heap.

Comment: @Harold L I believe Schwern is correct.

Comment: Not answering the question, but as a comment on thee code: Many suggest not to cast the return value of `malloc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `brk pointer` Not really, the code for `malloc()` can do anything it wants. What machine and architecture are you using? Do you use linux with glibc?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes. Sorry should have specified that

Comment: Nothing in the C/C++ standard mandates that anything must end on the stack, or even that the thing known as “stack” exists. You need to look in the assembly output to see what happens, as **all of it is implementation-defined**. I.e. the question should also state what exact compiler is spoken about, and what compiler options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only true answer is, wherever the compiler feels like. That's probably not the answer you want, so let's examine what a reasonable compiler would probably choose.

1. `cPtr` would probably not be stored in memory at all. It fits in a register (pointers almost always fit in CPU registers), and you never take its address, so it will probably be located in one or more registers. It might be written to stack and then read back to preserve its value across the `strncpy` and `printf` calls, or its value may be preserved in some other way. (Note that the compiler doesn't need to preserve its value after the `free` call, since you never use it again.)
2. `malloc` will almost always return a heap pointer, since that's where allocating dynamic memory is the easiest, if not the only possible location. So the buffer will be in the heap.
3. The compiler has a choice here. It might reference a linked `malloc` from some shared library, in which case it will reside in shared library code, or it might just inline all or part of the function, in which case some or all of it might reside in your program's code.
4. This assumes a POSIX environment. In every such environment I know, this is handled by a system call, `sbrk`. Thus, this code will reside within the operating system's kernel code.

EDIT: since some people mentioned the static string, `"Good luck on this test"`, I figured discussing that one would be worthwhile as well. This string appears in three contexts:

- as a *macro replacement* (through `#define`), which is handled by the preprocessor before compiling, and thus doesn't go anywhere at all in the final output;
- as an *argument to the `strncpy` function*, in which case it is included as read-only data, either together with the program's executable code or in a separate section made exclusively for read-only data;
- as an *argument to the `sizeof` operator*. This is the most interesting case of the three. Technically, it should be equivalent to the previous one; however, many compilers can statically calculate the size of a constant string (it's very straightforward, after all), and thus they can replace `sizeof(TEXT)` with a plain `23` and avoid emitting the string altogether (for that occurrence).

Comment: +1, but your last bullet about sizeof(TEXT) sounds like you're thinking of strlen, though: sizeof is compile time [except for variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336577/243245).

Comment: @Rup I'm not sure if this is true for all versions of C, though.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a bit of a leading question, because it presumes that everything will be in memory.

Local variables, as well as temporary values without a name, are only placed on the stack *if necessary*. There are different reasons why that might be necessary, for example:

- The compiler is dumb or made to act dumb by compiling at the lowest possible optimization level.
- The target machine has an odd architecture without (or very few) registers (rare).
- There are too many local variables and temporary values live simultaneously to fit them all into registers at that point in the program, so some of them get "spilled". Being spilled is not a property of a variable exactly, but rather of a specific live range. In some sense a variable can therefore move around (if it has multiple associated live ranges and they get allocated differently) and even be in multiple places simultaneously (depending on how you count temporary copies, or unambiguously when loop unrolling is involved).
- The address of the local variable is taken and used in such a way that the compiler cannot prove that the variable does not need to be in memory (may induce live range splitting so the variable is only actually in memory temporarily).

Most likely none of the above apply (the last item definitely does not apply, the address is not taken) so we should expect `cPtr` to spend its entire lifetime in registers.

Testing it out on [clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ssYXfj) targeting x64 we might get code like this:

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rbx
    mov     edi, 23
    call    malloc
    mov     rbx, rax

    ; at this point, rbx roughly corresponds to cPtr
    ; it's also still in rax but rax is overwritten by the next operation

    movabs  rax, 32777976875610985 ; btw this weird number is a piece of string
    mov     qword ptr [rbx + 15], rax
    movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .L.str]
    movups  xmmword ptr [rbx], xmm0

    ; rbx (cPtr) is copied to rdi in order to give it to puts as argument

    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    puts
    mov     rdi, rbx
    call    free
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbx
    ret
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Good luck on this test"
```

Targeting MIPS or ARM or PowerPC with eg GCC shows a similar pattern of `cPtr` not being on the stack but in a register (or several registers, depending on how you count), though of course the code looks pretty different.

A fun detail of the code above is that while the entire string does appear in a data segment (rodata), a piece of it also appears in the code segment as the immediate operand of that `movabs`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Stack
2. Heap
3. Data
4. Shared library

That is how i would answer this question.

1. `char * cPtr = NULL;` declares a char * on the stack and assigns it to point to NULL, In your instance the malloc() assignes it to point to heap memory but the cPtr variable itself is on the stack.
2. Malloc allocates heap memory.
3. The TEXT string is in data segment, and sizeof ("TEXT STRING") will be handled as an [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-an-operator) to an address in data segment.  I assume your question means the *"code for the arguments to malloc"*
4. Your code doesnt define the function malloc so whatever its doing must be happening due to one of the libraries you #included.

I may be wrong on one or more of these answers but that is my understanding.  If someone can tell me where I am wrong ill correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote without any comment!  It really helps me fix my answer.

Comment: Read other answers to understand what’s wrong. But in general, it’s misguided to talk about what a compiler might do: have you actually looked at what it does, or are you making stuff up? Have you ever checked how well you can predict what a compiler does by writing code, predicting, and checking actual output? You should well get the compiler and look at its output. It’s not magic. Godbolt compiler explorer exists for a reason: so that people don’t have to guess, as such guesses are incorrect more often than not.